# A word to describe a changed relationship

Tags: single-word-requests, past-participles

Suppose a boy & a girl were in a bosom relationship at one time, but now they are just good friends. With which word we can define this change in their relationship?

- Example: We are ______ now.

Which word should I use here to describe that our relationship has now changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common phrase is "just friends". Use of the "just" qualifier implies that this is a reduction from a previous state, and common sense implies that this must have been a romantic relationship.

Comment: Agree; We are just friends now. We are friends again. We are only friends.

Answer (score 0):

**My answer:**

> We are acquaintances now.

**Why I recommend this word:**

> An acquaintance is someone you know but don't have a close relationship with. This word in your example can imply the relationship has cooled down without any ambiguity to the listener's ears.

Comment: The question mentions that the pair are now "just good friends" which seems a closer relationship than _acquaintances_ would imply.

Comment: Imagine a girl telling a boy "we are just good friends." It leads to uncertainty that might make the boy think their relationship is still the same. In order to avoid that, I recommended using "acquaintance".